# How many centipawns guarantee winning?

Tags: computer-chess, evaluation

Since the question in this form is somewhat ill-defined,
I elaborate on it so it can be solved by experiment:

What is the maximum centipawn value you can come up with so that the weaker side holds a draw?

Assume two very strong deterministic (i.e., you only need one game) computers play out a position which is very bad (with value c centipawns) for one side, but the weaker side still draws. Say, two Leela copies. (Fortresses would be the first thing I'd try. But they neither may be solvable by tablebases nor a draw by 50 move/3 repetitions inside the horizon, otherwise it's an immediate 0.0!)

P.S. For a "normal" position I expect a guaranteed win somewhere in the evaluation range +2 to +3.

Answer (score 5):

This position [looks familiar](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/39113/longest-death-certificate/39115#39115), doesn't it? ;)

As you can [check on lichess](https://lichess.org/analysis/standard/kR6/p1p1p1p1/P1P1P1P1/p1p1p1p1/8/8/PKP1P1P1/8_b_-_-_0_1), the evaluation is nearly +8, and yet the position is as dead as it can be...

```
[Title "Diagram from Black's perspective"]
[FEN "kR6/p1p1p1p1/P1P1P1P1/p1p1p1p1/8/8/PKP1P1P1/8 b - - 0 1"] 
[startlfipped ""]
```

There are countless such examples, check [this](https://www.chess.com/article/view/10-positions-chess-engines-just-dont-understand) and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=15nuJdAUW0s).

If you want to know the *practical* winning centipawn threshold (arising in realistic games), my guess would be something near 1.5.

Comment: Yeah, 0.0 is about 1000 moves behind the horizon :-) (I still got a position which is +99 on LiChess, so you are not even close :P)

Comment: There will shortly be many queens on the board, and it's ""dead as it can be"?? Wait, is the diagram upside down???

Comment: @bof yes, it's from Black's point of view